# Compact operator on invariant subspace (not necessarily closed) is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators, invariant-subspace

I am looking at a problem in Conway's functional analysis text. It is problem II.5.7, which states: "If $T$ is compact and $\mathscr{M}$ is an invariant subspace for $T$, show that $T|_{\mathscr{M}}$ is compact."  I take this to mean that for every bounded sequence ${x_m}_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathscr{M}$, we need to show that there is a subsequence ${x_{m_k}}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $T|_{\mathscr{M}}x_{m_k} = Tx_{m_k}$ converges to some element $y$, and $y$ must be in $\mathscr{M}$.  If $\mathscr{M}$ is closed, this is pretty much trivial.  However, I am confused as to how to handle it when $\mathscr{M}$ is not closed.

Now there are seemingly various answers to this problem on StackExchange, but they all seem to ignore this fact that $y$ must be in $\mathscr{M}$. My question is: am I misunderstanding the problem, or is it stated incorrectly?  Thanks.

Comment: Your counterexample is really anything but.  An invariant subspace of a bounded operator $T$ is a closed *linear* subspace $\mathscr M$ such that $T\mathscr M\subset\mathscr M$, and $(0,1)$ is not a linear subspace of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: I reiterate: An invariant subspace is a **closed** linear subspace such that...

Comment: Ah so it was most certainly a misunderstanding of the definition, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the claim is false in general if the invariant subspace is not assumed to be closed.

Consider $T : \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ given by $T(x_n)_n = \left(\frac{x_n}n\right)_n$. Then $T$ is compact and $c_{00}$, the space of all finitely-supported sequences, is $T$-invariant.

Consider the sequence given by $y_n = \left(\frac12, \frac14, \ldots, \frac1{2^n}, 0, 0, \ldots\right) \in c_{00}$. Then $(y_n)_n$ converges to the vector $\left(\frac1{2^n}\right)_n \in \ell^2$ (in particular it is bounded) so $(Ty_n)_n$ converges to the vector $\left(\frac1{n2^n}\right)_n \in \ell^2 \setminus c_{00}$.

Hence there isn't a subsequence of $(Ty_n)_n$ which converges to a vector in $c_{00}$.

Comment: I am little confused by the notation $(x_n)_n$ could you elaborate? I am thinking these $n$'s are independent of each other?

Comment: @user707959 I changed the notation to $(x_n)_n$ and $(y_n)_n$. In $T(x_n)_n = \left(\frac{x_n}n\right)_n$, $(x_n)_n$ represents an element of $\ell^2$, i.e. it is a sequence of scalars. On the other hand, $(y_n)_n$ is a sequence in $\ell^2$, i.e. every $y_n$ is an element of $\ell^2$, given as  $y_n(k) = \begin{cases} \frac1{2^n}, &k \le n \\ 
0, & k > n
\end{cases}$ where $y_n = (y_n(k))_k$ so $y(k)$ is the $k$-th element of the sequence $y_n$.

Comment: Ok, this all makes sense, thank you! This was the intuition I had in a sequence sense, so thank you for making it concrete.